# RSpec for routes and testing routes.rb specifically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying to write test for my costume routes, along with non existing routes.

For the examples down here I have two problems:

1. It matches the actions that don't exist on my controller, so it doesn't really match to see if my controller have those actions, it just matches the syntax
2. the `should_not be_routable` doesn't work, which kind of goes back to the above problem of it doesn't check against my controller or the `routes.rb` file to see if the route should exist.

This one passes and is all good:

```
it "should route to method1" do
   { :get => '/my_controller/method1' }.should route_to(:controller => 'my_controller',
                                                     :action => 'method1')
end
```

this one fails, so it doesn't even check to see if I have a method zz defined in my controller or routes file.

```
it "should not route to zz" do
  { :get => '/my_controller/zz' }.should_not be_routable 
end
```

the error I get is:

```
MyController routing zz should route to rescan
     Failure/Error: { :get => '/my_controller/zz' }.should_not be_routable
       expected {:get=>"/client_rescan/zz"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:controller=>"my_controller", :action=>"zz"}
```

So it obviously doesn't look at my routes file at all...

This is another example of it doesn't look at my routes file, in my routes I have ' resources :client_rescan, :only => [:index] ' and when I do `rake routes` it doesn't show delete as expected, but the test doesn't look at those:

```
it "should not have route to delete" do
  { :delete => '/my_controller/1'}.should_not be_routable
end
```

The Failure I get is the following. Which looks like it doesn't even see the delete function:

```
 Failure/Error: { :delete => '/my_controller/1'}.should_not be_routable
   expected {:delete=>"/my_controller/1"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:controller=>"my_controller", :action=>"1"}
```

Another problem is my post routes to index in the test:

```
it "should not have route to post" do
  { :post => '/my_controller' }.should_not be_routable
end
```

The Failure I get is:

```
 Failure/Error: { :post => '/my_controller' }.should_not be_routable
   expected {:post=>"/my_controller"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:controller=>"my_controller", :action=>"index"}
```

this is content of my routes.rb file

```
require 'resque/server'
require 'resque_scheduler'

Cdc::Application.routes.draw do

  mount Resque::Server.new, :at => 'resque'
  Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'resque_schedule.yml')) # load the schedule

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions", :registrations => "registrations" }



  [:assessments, :security_assessments, :privacy_assessments].each do |assessment_type|
    resources assessment_type, :controller => :assessments do
      resources :rsz do
        post 'review', :on => :member
        get 'judgement', :on => :member
      end

      get :judgement, :on => :member

      resources :samples do
        get 'download', :on => :member
      end

      resources :asm_reviews do
        post :request_review, :on => :collection
      end
    end
  end



  resources :account_creator
  match "/images/captcha/*file_name" => "captcha#show"

  ## this is where my route is!! :)

  resources :my_controller, :only => [:index] do
    collection do
      get :rescan
      get :cancel
    end
  end

  match "alert_queue/words" => "alert_queue#words"
  resources :alert_queue

  match "calls_to_action/start/:id" => "calls_to_action#start", :id => /\d+/
  match "calls_to_action/close/:id" => "calls_to_action#close", :id => /\d+/
  match "calls_to_action/comment/:id" => "calls_to_action#comment", :id => /\d+/
  match "calls_to_action/multiclose" => "calls_to_action#multiclose"
  match "calls_to_action/multiscan" => "calls_to_action#multiscan"

  match "application_instances/multiclose" => "application_instances#multiclose"
  match "application_instances/multiscan" => "application_instances#multiscan"

  resources :code_categories do
    resources :code_families do
      resources :code_family_versions
    end
  end

  resources :code_policy_items


  resources :application_instances do
    collection do
      post :resque_statuses
    end

    resources :code_indices
    resources :application_analysis

    get "smali/:smali_path", :as => :smali, :on => :member, :action => :smali, :smali_path => /.*/
    member do
      get :file
      get :strings
      get :dump
      get :alerts
      get :correlations
      get :signers
      get :icon
      get :resque_status
      get :assets
      get :new_code_index
      get :class_list
      get :heuristic_hits
      get :engine_artifacts
      post :rescan
      post :attach_artifact
      post :engine_artifact, :action => :attach_engine_artifact
      resources :alerts
    end

    post "multiscan", :on => :collection, :action => :multiscan
    post "multiclose", :on => :collection, :action=> :multiclose
    post "engines/:engine_name/:engine_version/assertions/:cookie",
         :on => :member, :action => :register_assertion_set, :as => :register_assertion_set,
         :engine_name => /[^\/]+/, :engine_version => /[^\/]+/, :cookie => /[^\/]+/
    post "engines/:engine_name/:engine_version/network_data",
         :on => :member, :action => :register_network_data, :as => :register_network_data,
         :engine_name => /[^\/]+/, :engine_version => /[^\/]+/

    post "assets", :on => :member, :action => :register_asset_set, :as => :register_asset_set
  end

  # index gets the list of families, show gets the assertion types for that family
  resources :assertion_families

  resources :artifacts

  resources :dashboard do
    collection do
      get :last_app_instance
    end
  end

  match '/direct_downloads/' => 'direct_downloads#index'

  root :to => "stats#index"
  match '/' => 'stats#index'
  match 'explorer/query/:format' => 'explorer#query'
  match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
end
```

Comment: Is that last test passing or failing? If failing, what's the error you get?

Comment: sorry, i just updated the question with the error. so pretty much thinks `but it routes to {:controller=>"my_controller", :action=>"1"`

Comment: @Meena Sorry, but your comment "so pretty much thinks but it routes to " doesn't make any sense. Can you re-read it and update it?

Comment: @99miles sorry I didn't explain much because I put the respond as part of the qeustion body, so people don't have to read the comments. so the error I get is the same as above and it's:  ` Failure/Error: { :delete => '/my_controller/1'}.should_not be_routable
   expected {:delete=>"/my_controller/1"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:controller=>"my_controller", :action=>"1"}`

Comment: Could you post the contents of your routes.rb file, along with the output of rake routes?

Comment: Note that routing specs will *not* look at the controller actions to see whether or not they exist. Routing specs work like unit tests for routes -- they should not depend on controllers, models, etc. In other words, if you specify a route to a non-existent action, the routing spec will still pass.

Comment: @cheeseweasel I copied the content on the bottom of the question. thanks!

Comment: @zetetic but it must look at routes.rb if an action is not defined there it shouldn't match it, right? thats's why the `should_not be_routable
` exists. Or at least if I specify only `index` it should not have routes for `delete` and the rest?

Comment: @Meena, well it looks like you have some sort of catchall going on, maybe somewhere else in your routes.rb? That's why I wanted to see routes.rb, and the output of rake routes. What happens if you browse to `/my_controller/zz` in the development app?

Comment: @cheeseweasel going to /my_controller/zz gives me this error: Unknown action

The action 'zz' could not be found for ClientRescanController

Comment: It definitely looks like you have a catchall route, I don't think the problem is in the `resources :my_controller` definition, I think it's elsewhere in `routes.rb`. If you could show us more of routes.rb, it might help. You can leave out resources definitions if you like.

Comment: thanks @cheeseweasel , I put the routes.rb up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line of routes.rb:

```
match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

This is a catch all route, and will match for example /abc/xyz to controller abc, and action xyz.

It's best really not to use catch all routes, in favour of exposing only the functionality you want.

Comment: A big fist shake to every contractor who doomed future developers with this!